# Datamaps isn't showing map of Central America country

Tags: javascript, d3.js, datamaps

I'm trying to build a map of a country named El Salvador with Datamaps. But for whatever reason, it doesn't show and there isn't any warning or error message displayed.

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/topojson/1.6.9/topojson.min.js"></script>
<script src="datamaps.slv.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="position: relative; width: 500px; height: 300px;"></div>
<script>
 var map = new Datamap({element: document.getElementById('container'),scope: 'slv'});
</script>
```

I'm using the correct library (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/markmarkoh/datamaps/master/dist/datamaps.slv.js). The above code works fine if a use a world map (deleting the scope line).

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set "transform projection" for the location for "El Salvador", this location is [-88.9195598, 13.7734784], the lat and lng is need to be set in that order.